# Can't get RVM to switch rubies

Tags: ruby, shell, rvm, fish

How do I explicitly point my fish shell to RVM's version of rubies?

I'm using fish shell and I installed RVM. However, no matter what I do, RVM doesn't want to switch rubies.

```
rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.3.0 [ x86_64 ]

> ruby -v                                                             
ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]

> rvm use ruby-2.3.0
Using /Users/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0

> ruby -v                                                             
ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]
```

my config.fish file contains: rvm default

What am i doing wrong here?

UPDATES:

```
> which ruby                                                                                                                                         
/usr/bin/ruby

which -a ruby                                                                                                                                      
/usr/bin/ruby

echo $PATH                                                                                                                                         
/usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin
```

It seems like the path might be wrong, but i'm not sure and not sure how to correct it.

EDIT 2:

Now I changed the path, but it still isn't working:

```
> echo $PATH                                                          
/Users/.../.rvm/bin /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin
```

Comment: Start a fresh shell. If it does not help, provide the information on what shell do you use. It’s config should be updated.

Comment: Is your `PATH` properly set up to use RVM's Ruby rather than the system Ruby? What does `which ruby` say from the command line? How about `which -a ruby`?

Comment: Advice: use `ruby-install` and `chruby`. They are much simpler to use. RVM is such bloatware

Comment: @muistooshort both say /usr/bin/ruby

Comment: @mudasobwa using fish shell

Comment: Append this line to your `~/.profile` file to load RVM environment: `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting`.

Comment: @mudasobwa I already have this in that file: `
# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
`

Comment: @mudasobwa i tried adding the line you mentioned and it didn't work

Comment: Did you download and install the RVM fish functions as described [here](https://rvm.io/integration/fish)? I guess you might have to relogin into your shell after installation, too.

Comment: Acording to rvm man page fish shell is not supported out of the box. You can find additional notes on the rvm site under "Integration" => "Fish"

Comment: @BoraMa yes, I installed the RVM fish functions

Comment: @slowjack2k yes, i followed those instructions

Comment: I think it would be good to add fish shell to your topic and tags. It's an uncommen setup your using and you need some one with experience with fish shell to look into this.

Comment: @slowjack2k I just tried switching back to bash shell and it actually has the same problem...this is something with the shell not pointing to the RVM ruby directory

Comment: Did you also rollback the changes within rvm for fish shell?

Comment: @slowjack2k I think so

Comment: Hey @MatthewBerman, have you tried to install the ruby version through RVM (`$ rvm install 2.3.0`) and then use it (`$ rvm use 2.3`)?  After that `$ ruby -v` should give you the current version being used by RVM(2.3.0) and `$ which ruby` should now point you to a different path then the one you see above, something like (/home/mpapis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby).  Let me know if that helped.  Thanks.

Comment: Alternatively if the above does not work, you can try to use the following commands.  Delete the current default(`rvm alias delete default`) and create a new one(` rvm alias create default 2.3.0`).  Referenced from SO earlier answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632066/cant-change-rvm-default)

Comment: @Matthew Berman Did you download and install the fish shell RVM helper code from Github, as instructed on https://rvm.io/integration/fish ?

Comment: [This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25786967/1607133) fixed this for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a silly observation, but after installing from github:

```
curl -L --create-dirs -o ~/.config/fish/functions/rvm.fish https://raw.github.com/lunks/fish-nuggets/master/functions/rvm.fish
```

did you configure the rvm defaul like this?:

```
echo "rvm default" >> ~/.config/fish/config.fish
```

Comment: I did, and I am still having a PATH problem for finding the correct `ruby` version, and any of my gem executables.  Found those instructions here: https://rvm.io/integration/fish